# How do I return a Number object of the same concrete type as one passed in?

Tags: java, constructor, casting

I have the following incomplete class. It implements a method that takes any `Number` object as a parameter and constrains it to a limit stored in a long and then returns the original value or the constrained value. However, the returned constrained value must be of the same concrete type as the input parameter.

```
public class Max implements Constraint {

    long max;

    public Number constrain(Number n) {
        if (n.longValue() <= max) {
            return n;
        }
        // return a number of the type passed in with value max
    }
}
```

There are other questions about creating an object of the same type as another, but the answers assume a no-arg constructor is available and this is not the case for the numeric types.

I have played with:

```
n.getClass().getConstructor(new Class<?>[] { n.getClass() }).newInstance(max);
```

but I still have issues about passing in the right parameter even here. I am back to square one. In any case, it isn't very elegant.

I know I can do it with a lot of `if` statements, but I am looking for something smarter.

Comment: Note: I've upvoted a couple of answers that proposed going via strings, even though I did think of it and rejected it because its quite nasty. However, I was really  looking for an answer that was a bit cleaner.

Comment: But you cannot have a generic solution without using String, because it's the only generic method between subclasses of Number

Comment: And it's not because that we're looking for a clean answer that it does exists

Comment: Maybe it doesn't exist. But that is the challenge. I tried playing with Class.cast() but it would give me what I wanted.

Comment: @rghome I am struggling to understand what you are trying to implement - could you please provide example inputs/outputs?

Comment: Ther is only one Generic way (without if/..) and it's using String constructor (see my answer), dont know why you're looking something that does not exist

Comment: (Class) n.getClass().getDeclaredField("TYPE").get(n) should be able to return the proper argument type of the constructor if the type of n is primitive.

Answer (score 1):

Because the constuctor of SubClasses of `Number` takes `primitives` as parameter, you cannot look for the constructore that has the `Wrapper Class` as parameter

The constructor that they all have, is the `String` one

```
long max;

public Number constrain(Number n) {
    if (n.longValue() <= max) 
       try{
           return n.getClass()
                .getConstructor(String.class)
                .newInstance(String.valueOf(max));
       }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    return n;
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    Max m = new Max();
    m.max = 10;
    System.out.println(m.constrain(new Double(25)).getClass()); // class java.lang.Double
    System.out.println(m.constrain((int) 18).getClass());       // class java.lang.Integer
}
```

---

[***Working DEMO***](https://ideone.com/QXO4lC)

Answer (score 0):

### Edit - v3 - without String.

If you only talk about members of Numbers that allows primitive type as the input of constructor like Float/Double/Integer/Long/..., the following could work:

```
    //Number n is valid someInput;
    //Note this only works for Classes that take a single numeric value as input
    Class type = (Class) n.getClass().getDeclaredField("TYPE").get(n);
    return n.getClass().getConstructor(type).newInstance(max)
```

Things like BigInteger will not work with this one.

### Edit - v2

It seems like, for primitive types n, if the "Number n" is replaced by different signatures and by using Integer.TYPE (or Float.TYPE and etc.) you might pass in the 'int' as parameters of getConstructor. You may use n.TYPE here (but as a reminder TYPE is the class member, and it may pop some warning).

```
    n.getClass().getConstructor(n.TYPE).newInstance(max);
```

Still, as @azro pointed out: if you insist not using string and want it smart, you still need branches and it could be nastier: you need to consider all subclasses of Number, including BigInteger.

True, casting it to string is nasty, but otherwise, you may need to wrap each subclass of Number with an extra class that allows the non-primitive type as args of the constructor. I barely think if-statements is nastier.

#### Original Answer

I am not very familiar with Reflection.
But a major problem here is the constructor of Numbers are either String or primitive types like 'int', and you cannot really utilize 'int' as the input of getConstructor.

at least, the following may work.

```
    //assume n is some Number object.
    n.getClass().getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(max.toString());
```

This works as classes like Float/Integer/BigInt.../ have constructors that take String as the input.

Comment: And how to find the type ? make if on `instance of`, then get the constructor and else ? and you cannot call floatValue, intVlue() ... on same instance, it can't have multiple values like this

Comment: This is not an answer, you make supposition, and possiblities, but nothing that works

Comment: @azro as stated, use getField. It only works for constructors with primitive input. The string version in the original answer shall work for all current subclasses of Number.

Comment: @azro I simply doubt why OP struggle for so-called "smart" while the overall readability and even efficiency are sacrificed.

Answer (score 0):

with Java 5 or hogher you can use a generic in your methods like this

```
package test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.junit.Assert;

public class Max {

    Number max;

    public <T extends Number> T constrain(T n) {
        if (n.floatValue() <= max.floatValue()) {
            return n;
        } else {
            return castTo(max, n.getClass());
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T extends Number> T castTo(Number max2, Class<? extends Number> class1) {
        if (class1.equals(AtomicInteger.class)) {
            return (T) new AtomicInteger(max2.intValue());
        } else if (class1.equals(AtomicLong.class)) {
            return (T) new AtomicLong(max2.longValue());

            // these case are dangerous to handle
        } else if (class1.equals(BigDecimal.class)) {
            return (T) BigDecimal.valueOf(max2.doubleValue());
        } else if (class1.equals(BigInteger.class)) {
            return (T) BigInteger.valueOf(max2.longValue());

            // Std Case
        } else if (class1.equals(Byte.class)) {
            return (T) (Byte) max2.byteValue();
        } else if (class1.equals(Double.class)) {
            return (T) (Double) max2.doubleValue();
        } else if (class1.equals(Float.class)) {
            return (T) (Float) max2.floatValue();
        } else if (class1.equals(Integer.class)) {
            return (T) (Integer) max2.intValue();
        } else if (class1.equals(Long.class)) {
            return (T) (Long) max2.longValue();
        } else if (class1.equals(Short.class)) {
            return (T) (Short) max2.shortValue();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't handle this kind of Number : " + class1.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Max max = new Max();
        max.max = 32;
        Integer constrain = max.constrain(33);
        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.class, constrain.getClass());
        Assert.assertEquals(max.max, constrain);

        Double constrain2 = max.constrain(33d);
        Assert.assertEquals(Double.class, constrain2.getClass());
        Assert.assertEquals(max.max.doubleValue(), constrain2, 0);

        Float constrain3 = max.constrain(33f);
        Assert.assertEquals(Float.class, constrain3.getClass());
        Assert.assertEquals(max.max.floatValue(), constrain3, 0);

        Short constrain4 = max.constrain((short) 33);
        Assert.assertEquals(Short.class, constrain4.getClass());
        Assert.assertEquals(max.max.shortValue(), constrain4, 0);

        Byte constrain5 = max.constrain((byte) 33);
        Assert.assertEquals(Byte.class, constrain5.getClass());
        Assert.assertEquals(max.max.byteValue(), constrain5, 0);

        Long constrain6 = max.constrain(33l);
        Assert.assertEquals(Long.class, constrain6.getClass());
        Assert.assertEquals(max.max.longValue(), constrain6, 0);

        BigDecimal constrain7 = max.constrain(BigDecimal.valueOf(33));
        Assert.assertEquals(BigDecimal.class, constrain7.getClass());
        BigInteger constrain8 = max.constrain(BigInteger.valueOf(33));
        Assert.assertEquals(BigInteger.class, constrain8.getClass());

        AtomicInteger constrain9 = max.constrain(new AtomicInteger(33));
        Assert.assertEquals(AtomicInteger.class, constrain9.getClass());
        AtomicLong constrain10 = max.constrain(new AtomicLong(33));
        Assert.assertEquals(AtomicLong.class, constrain10.getClass());

    }
}
```

but inside your code to construct all child of number there no common constructor the safest way is to reduce the case you want handle here i didn't handle all Striped64 children

Answer (score 0):

I discovered:

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils;

...

return (Number)ConvertUtils.convert(max, n.getClass());
```

I haven't looked at the source, but I doubt it is very clever inside. I believe it just hosts a collection of type converters.

So this is an alternative - not better than the other answers, but at least it is concise.